# Calling depends targets from parent build.xml inside includes xml

Tags: ant, build

Is it possible for xml files that are part of 'includes' inside build.xml to have depends on targets from that build.xml (backwards dependency)? Or do I need to create a chain of only forward dependencies, and having "depends" on includedFile.target down? If this is possible, how do I call these parent targets?

I am trying to extract several targets outside of a very long build.xml file, in a situation like this:

build.xml defines a very common target, buildMe used throughout the build.xml file. It also defines a target runTasks. It includes someTasks.xml. runTasks depends on buildMe and someTasks.groupOfTasks.

someTasks.xml define targets groupOfTasks, task0, task1, task2. groupOfTasks depends on task0, task1 and task2. Now can task0 task1 or task2 depend on buildMe from build.xml, or some other target defined in build.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me: In the main project file the target default depends on a target from `commontasks.xml` which depends on a target from the main project file:

```
<project name="main" default="default">

  <import file="commontasks.xml" as="common" />

  <target name="default" depends="common.hello" description="the main project">
  </target>

  <target name="initMain">
    <echo>initializing main</echo>
    <property name="aValue" value="MAIN" />
  </target>
```

```
<project name="commontasks" >

  <target name="hello" depends="initMain">
    <echo>hello from common tasks</echo>
    <echo>aValue: ${aValue}</echo>
  </target>
```

When I run the ant build, I get:

```
initMain:
 [echo] initializing main
common.hello:
 [echo] hello from common tasks
 [echo] aValue: MAIN
default:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

The dependency is target `default` depends on `hello` depends on `initMain` and `hello` can use properties defined in `initMain`.

Comment: Working for me too now. I think the difference is I did not have as="" in the import statement or my import was not the first statement of build.xml. Thanks!

Comment: According to the ant documentation about the as attribute `If omitted, the name attribute of the project tag of the imported file will be used.`. In my example the imported task should then be available as `commontasks.hello`.

Comment: I also realized I was using include instead of import, but I thought they were the same, just import allowed targets to be overridden.