# Ant how call another xml file from build.xml depending parameter

Tags: java, ant

I have a 3 xml files `build.xml, build_1.xml, build_2.xml`. The `build_1.xml, build_2.xml` files have target with name '`compress`'.

How can I configure `build.xml` file that when I call '`ant compress 1`' it run compress target from `build_1.xml` file and accordingly run compress target from `build_2.xml` in case of '`ant compress 2`'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25207678/1422630, thru depends="" we can chose the other xml target

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html

as I understand your question you would need the following 2 targets in your build.xml file:

```
<target name="ant compress 1">
    <ant antfile="build_1.xml" target="compress"/>
</target>

<target name="ant compress 2">
    <ant antfile="build_2.xml" target="compress"/>
</target>
```

Comment: any way to create a call for the "ant compress 1" from within another target on the build.xml?

Comment: I ended importing the file and using `depends` http://stackoverflow.com/a/25207678/1422630